# How to make a middleware that can call database to check user claims to authorize a user in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2, claims, ef-core-2.2

What is the best practice to make a middleware or a proper way to implement middleware in asp.net core 2.2.

My Scenario is
I have a web api build in asp.net core 2.2 and I implement authorization in my controller something like this `[Authorize(Policy = "UserDelete")]` `UserDelete` is a user claim my problem is i have many user claim can user have, more or less up to 20 claims if I save this claims in JWT it can cause large size of JWT all i want to do is to call claims or create a middleware that call the database for this claims so that all i need to save in JWT is user credentials.

Comment: The JWT isn't "user credentials", it's the authenticated principal. That's how this works. The whole concept is disconnected from the anything like a database or persistence - by design. The app doesn't need to know or care where the principal came from or how it was created. It just works with it and its claims. As such, the claims are inseparable, as that's what defines the principal. It is literally a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to create an AuthorizationHandler, please follow the instructions:
1- create a class and name it `MinimumPermissionHandler` or whatever. copy and paste following codes in it:

```
public class MinimumPermissionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

public class MinimumPermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumPermissionRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumPermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!(context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        //check if token has subjectId
        var subClaim = context.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub");
        if (subClaim == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        //check if token is expired
        var exp = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "exp")?.Value;
        if(exp == null || new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(long.Parse(exp)).ToLocalTime() < DateTime.Now)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        //other checkpoints
        //your db functions to check if user has desired claims

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

2- Define a policy and add the handler to services, so put this lines in your Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //deleted extra lines for brevity 
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
      options.AddPolicy("AccessControl", policy =>
      {
           policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
           policy.AddRequirements(new MinimumPermissionRequirement());
      });
   });
   //injection
   services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumPermissionHandler>();
}
```

3- Finally for checking access permission just put this code above Controllers

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AccessControl")]
```

Comment: How to put it against all controllers / endpoints ? I use currently .net5 so I added             app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>{ endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization()

Comment: just input the policyName to the RequireAuthorization like `endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("AccessControl")`