# AuthorizeAttribute with Roles not working when migrating from MVC to Endpoint Routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upgrade my project from .UseMVC (asp.net core 2.2 compat style) to .UseEndpoint Routing and I'm getting re-directed to my suthentication failed page for all my requests. It has to do with the Claims - If I remove the role part of [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] to simply [Authorize] then it works. It seems that it isn't picking up the claims that are assigned to the user.

It seems to be a very similar issue as [AuthorizeAttribute not working with Endpoint Routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60388730/5683904)

The following paragraph is an excerpt from the linked post *but modified to reflect my version of the issue*

> **Everything worked fine in 2.2, but after migrating to 3.1 and enabling
> Endpoint Routing, this controller began to refuse requests to any
> endpoint when [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] attribute is present.** When I remove
> "Roles =" part and look at User.Claims, I can see that it does have the
> required claims/roles. This happens
> only if Endpoint Routing is enabled, in case of using UseMvc
> everything works properly. What's wrong with Authorization in Endpoint
> Routing mode?

Excerpt from Startup.cs

```
 app.UseSession();
    
 app.UseRouting();
    
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.UseResponseCompression();
 //Add the users Roles as claims to his identity so that it is picked up for authentication purposes
 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
     var userId = context.User.Identity.Name;
     if (userId == null)
     {
         return next();
     }
    
     ...
        
     var roles = resourceDataAccess.GetRolesForUser(userId);
     if (roles != null)
     {
         var claims = roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.RoleEnum.ToString())).ToList();
    
         var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
         context.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
     }
    
     return next();
 });
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapHub<AppHub>("api/apphub");
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller=Account}/{action=SignIn}/{id?}");
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute("catch-all", "api/{*url}",
             new {controller = "Utility", action = "NotFoundPage"});
 });
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but could you try to put `UseAuthorization` after your role mapper middleware?

Comment: you can follow this instruction by using middleware 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320523/how-to-make-a-middleware-that-can-call-database-to-check-user-claims-to-authoriz/56323036#56323036

Comment: That link is about creating policies. What we want to do is to use the built-in roles based authentication. For some reason it is not respecting the roles that we provide and assing to the user.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - your answer solved the question.  UseAuthentication needs to be before the mapping code and UseAuthorization after.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out since we were using app.Use() middleware to fill in the user's roles from the DB, it needed to be called before UseAuthorisation so that the roles were loaded before authorisation was performed. (Like @CamiloTerevinto's comment)

```
 app.UseSession();
    
 app.UseRouting();
    
 app.UseAuthentication();
 //Add the users Roles as claims to his identity so that it is picked up for authentication purposes
 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
   ...
 }
 //Setup the authorisation middleware to run only after we have loaded the users roles.
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.UseResponseCompression();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you could solve the problem. It seemed incorrect to me given that the order of the UseXXX is the order the code is invoked